# How do you make a tutorial page in Sphinx?

Tags: python, python-sphinx

I get how to use numpy docstrings to document the individual classes and methods and so on, but I also want to have a page that shows the users how to use my package in our facility's environment (i.e. how to access the Jupyter notebook, how to load my package into it, how to set up the environment, and how to use it in practice). Is there a way to do this directly in Sphinx? Or will I need to build the HTML page using another program?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yep! Generally when you want to write prose documentation, you'd write it directly into your reStructuredText files in your Sphinx docs directory.

So, for instance, you'd create an `installation.rst` which might look like this:

```
Installation
============

To access the Jupyter notebook, go to `this site <https://example.com>`_
```

Then, you'd edit your Table of Contents in `index.rst` to look something like this:

```
.. toctree::
   :maxdepth: 2

   installation
   some_other_preexisting_page
   another_preexisting_page
```

(This is all assuming your Sphinx setup looks somewhat similar to what `sphinx-quickstart` creates.)